# ¿Por qué no se actualiza el tamaño del 'Array'?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Teniendo dos vistas, A y B, en la vista B capturo el color asociado a un `button` y el nombre que digita el usuario asociado a un `textField`. Creando un protocolo  asigno esos valores al método del mismo protocolo  y  los uso en el archivo `ColorsViewController` que va a ser el delegado.

El problema es el siguiente : todo va bien en la parte de `CreateViewController` pues verificando después de pulsar en el botón guardar y regresar a la vista A estan los datos,  pero se quiere mostrar estos datos en un `tableView`. Como se sabe, al implementar el `dataSource` para el `tableView` se requiere  el método `numberOfRowsInSection`. Hasta el momento me he dado cuenta que al momento de hacer el `name!.append(name)` el sí asigna los datos al arreglo, pero como ya cargo la tabla  que en un principio toma como referencia el `name!.count`que cuando empieza la ejecución es 0 después de que se le añade los datos al arreglo es como si no actualizara que los  nuevos elemento que se están añadiendo.

Estos son el archivo que intervienen Vista A

```
import UIKit

class ColorsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,CreateColorViewControllerDelegate{

var names: [String]?
var colors: [UIColor]?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from           a nib

    names = Array()
    colors = Array()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Navigation
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    let identifier = segue.identifier
    if identifier == "CreateColor" {
        let createColor = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateColorViewController
        createColor.delegate = self
    }

}

func createColor(name: String, color: UIColor) {
    names!.append(name)
    colors!.append(color)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell?.backgroundColor  = colors![indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel!.text = names![indexPath.row]

    return cell!

}

}
```

El segundo archivo es este Vista B

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol CreateColorViewControllerDelegate{
   func createColor(name:String, color:UIColor)
}


class CreateColorViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

weak var delegate:CreateColorViewControllerDelegate?

weak var selectedButton: UIButton?

@IBOutlet weak var colorTextField: UITextField!


@IBAction func colorSelected(sender: UIButton) {

    if selectedButton   != nil {

        selectedButton!.layer.borderColor = nil
        selectedButton!.layer.borderWidth = 0.0

    }

    //sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 5.0


    selectedButton = sender


}

@IBAction func save(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let name = colorTextField.text

    let color = UIColor(CGColor: (selectedButton!.layer.backgroundColor)!)

    if name!.isEmpty{
        let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Espera", message: "Coloca Un Nombre", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let alertaCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        let alertSucces = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)

        alerta.addAction(alertaCancel)
        alerta.addAction(alertSucces)

        self.presentViewController(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else{

        delegate?.createColor(name!, color: color)
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }



}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

El `tableView` no sabe cuando hay nuevos datos y es necesario que se lo indiques. Lo único que te faltaría es hacer un reload de la tabla cuando se llama el delegado en la vista A. Es decir;

```
func createColor(name: String, color: UIColor) {
    names!.append(name)
    colors!.append(color)
    tableView.reloadData() // Reload del tableView
}
```

Con esto, ya te debería de funcionar correctamente.

Comment: En efecto tenias toda la razón lo unico que tambien me faltaba era hacerle una referencia como un `Outlet` al `UITableView`para poderle aplicar  el metodo `reloadData()`